# Writing Unit Test Case in Angular JS using Karma

Tags: angularjs

I am building an application using Angular JS. As I am new to it I don't know much about writing test cases in it.

Suppose i have function:

```
function getAvailablePolicyTypes() {
            return [
                { key: '', value: '' },
                { key: 'P', value: 'P-Primary' },
                { key: 'D', value: 'D-Dependent' }
            ];
        }
```

How I write test case for this ?

I was doing like this

```
    it('should create Policy type with 3 values', function () {

        expect(vm.availablePolicyTypes.length).toBe(3);


    });
```

Comment: You can't test private functions directly, and you don't have to.

Comment: How are you exposing that method?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question about jasmine as there's nothing in your description that has anything to do with either karma or angularjs.

For that test, I'd be using toEqual(3) instead of toBe(3), otherwise it looks good.

[Jasmine docs](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/)